# document.[form element] is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form that is defined like this:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkMyCheckbox" id="chkMyCheckbox"/>
</form>
```

I am simply trying to get the value of the checkbox in window.onload. For that, I do this:

```
window.onload = function()
{
   var checkboxValue = document.myForm.chkMyCheckbox.checked;
}
```

On loading the page, I receive the error "document.myForm is undefined". If I'm referencing the form after the page is loaded, why am I seeing this error?

Answer (score 2):

You should try using `document.onload` instead of `window.onload`.  `document.onload` is when the DOM is ready, hence `myForm` will be instantiated and shouldn't be undefined at that point.

```
document.onload = function()
{
   var checkboxValue = document.myForm.chkMyCheckbox.checked;
}
```

Comment: When I put document.onload = function(){ alert('loaded');} into my page, it never fires (or the alert never displays).